# Read Csv using LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

I am having a csv file like this

```
A, 22, 23, 12
B, 32, 4, 33
C, 34, 3 ,33
```

I want to print the sum and average of each row and skip the first column. How to do in LINQ using Lambda

Answer (score 43, accepted):

```
var stuff = from l in File.ReadAllLines(filename)
            let x = l.Split(new [] {',', ' '}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
                     .Skip(1)
                     .Select(s => int.Parse(s))
            select new
            {
                Sum = x.Sum(),
                Average = x.Average()
            };
```

If you're reading big files and memory use is a concern, then the following will work better using .NET 4:

```
var stuff = from l in File.ReadLines(filename)
            let x = l.Split(new [] {',', ' '}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
                     .Skip(1)
                     .Select(s => int.Parse(s))
            select new
            {
                Sum = x.Sum(),
                Average = x.Average()
            };
```

In both cases, the `stuff` variable contains an enumerable which won't actually be executed until you start reading from it (e.g. inside a `foreach` loop).

Comment: Don't forget to convert strings to integers. `X = (int)x[1]` won't compile. Try using `Int32.Parse()` or `Convert.ToInt32()`.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I've fixed it, and simplified the query a bit by using the built in aggregates.

Comment: Not exactly as it is, but if you're using .NET 4, just change `ReadAllLines` to `ReadLines`.

Comment: @Mou: the difference is `ReadLines` in the second example. `ReadAllLines` loads the entire file into a string array in memory, but `ReadLines` reads one line at a time as an `IEnumerable<string>`, which will perform better for very large files.

Comment: Splitting on comma is a bad idea, data can contain commas.

Comment: Depends on your input. The OP's example contains single letter labels and numbers only. If that's all you ever have to process there's no reason not to just split on commas.

Comment: If you have text data which may contain commas, then you obviously shouldn't split on commas. But you probably shouldn't be trying to process it with LINQ either. There are better tools for the job.

Comment: If you have commas as data in your CSV file, then you need a proper CSV Parser. LINQ isn't going to be able to handle that.

Answer (score 8):

```
        string csvFile = @"myfile.csv";
        string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(csvFile);

        var values = lines.Select(l => new { FirstColumn = l.Split(',').First(), Values = l.Split(',').Skip(1).Select(v => int.Parse(v)) });
        foreach (var value in values)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Column '{0}', Sum: {1}, Average {2}", value.FirstColumn, value.Values.Sum(), value.Values.Average()));
        }
```

Comment: Splitting on comma is a bad idea, data can contain commas.

Answer (score 7):

Try to use this old but still good library: [`FileHelpers Library`](http://filehelpers.sourceforge.net/)

It's very easy to use:

```
char delimiter = ',';
var dt = FileHelpers.CsvEngine.CsvToDataTable(fileName,delimiter);
```

then just do:

```
var rowStats = dt.AsEnumerable()
                 .Select(x => x.ItemArray.Select(y => Convert.ToInt32(y)))
                 .Select(x => new { avg = x.Average(), sum = x.Sum() });

foreach (var rowStat in rowStats)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Sum: {0}, Avg: {1}", rowStat.sum, rowStat.avg);
}
```

Comment: +1 for using FileHelpers, although personally I'd create a custom type instead of resorting to DataTable in order to increase readability tremendously.

Comment: @Martin:  Yes you're right, but of course you can use a Type only if the CSV file has always the same structure (e.g the same number of columns)

Answer (score 5):

```
string[] csvlines = File.ReadAllLines(@txtCSVFile.Text);

var query = from csvline in csvlines
  let data = csvline.Split(',')
  select new
  {
   ID = data[0],
   FirstNumber = data[1],
   SecondNumber = data[2],
   ThirdNumber = data[3]
  };
```

Comment: You need to add the aggregation over the projection

Comment: Splitting on comma is a bad idea, data can contain commas.

Answer (score 4):

I just have discovered LinqToCsv library, it do all the parsing stuff and then you can query objects like collections and it supports deferred reading:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/25133/LINQ-to-CSV-library

Comment: This is a great library. Thanks for recommending it

Comment: Great library for CSV related stuffs. Simply exceptional.

Answer (score 3):

Actually for most cases you should avoid splitting based on `','` only because you could have coma in string.

I give you a better generic solution using Regex and easy to use:

```
var stuff = File.ReadAllLines(csvFilePath)
    .Skip(1) // For header
    .Select(s => Regex.Match(s, @"^(.*?),(.*?),(.*?),(.*?),(.*?)$"))
    .Select(data => new 
    {
        Foo = data.Groups[1].Value,
        Bar = data.Groups[2].Value,
        One = data.Groups[3].Value,
        Two = data.Groups[4].Value,
    });
```

And you can find more details here https://stackoverflow.com/a/18147076/196526

Comment: Thank you for the -1. I like to know when I'm doing something wrong. Could you please tell me why -1 because this is the only valid solution when working with csv file that contains strings. Is it because it is not good practice to use Regex or because this answer is too generic for the question or maybe you just don't like Regex? Why this bad reaction.

Comment: This doesn't solve the splitting by comma problem at all. RegEx is hungry by default and this would parse it weird and put the comma in the first field all the time, not to mention the comma is normally wrapped in quotes for it to be valid so now you have quotes showing up in your data. If you have commas in your data, you need a proper CSV Parser.

Answer (score 0):

Hi 
you are looking for something like this

```
  var rows = new List<string> {"A, 22, 23, 12", "B, 32, 4, 33", "C, 34, 3 ,33"};
     foreach (var row in rows) {
            var sum = row.Split(',').Skip(1).Sum(x => Convert.ToInt32(x));
            var avg = row.Split(',').Skip(1).Average(x => Convert.ToInt32(x));
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this maybe:

```
var csv = @"A, 22, 23, 12
B, 32, 4, 33
C, 34, 3 ,33";

var lines =
    csv.Split('\n').Select(x => x.Split(',').Skip(1).Select(n => int.Parse(n))).Select(x => new {Sum = x.Sum(), Average = x.Average()});
foreach (var line in lines)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Sum: " + line.Sum);
    Console.WriteLine("Average: " + line.Average);
}
```

In general, I don't suggest to do something like this. You should use a full blown CSV reader to parse the CSV file and you should include error handling.

Answer (score 0):

```
using System.IO

// turn file into IEnumerable (streaming works better for larger files)
IEnumerable<Tuple<int, int, int>> GetTypedEnumerator(string FilePath){
  var File = File.OpenText(FilePath);
  while(!File.EndOfStream) 
      yield return new Tuple<int, int, int>(
          Int.Parse(File[1]), 
          Int.Parse(File[2], 
          Int.Parse(File[3])
      );
   File.Close();
}

// this lines would return the sum and avg for each line
var tot = GetTypeEnumerator(@"C:\file.csv").Select(l=>l.Item1 + l.Item2 + l.Item3);
var avg = GetTypeEnumerator(@"C:\file.csv").Select(l=> (l.Item1 + l.Item2 + l.Item3) / 3);
```

The streaming aporoach will let you handle laregr files because you wouldn;t need toload them into memeory first.
Don't have VS here, haven't checked the syntax, might not compile as is.

Regards GJ

Damn, lot of answers already, need to type faster!